# Page breaks after zooming in and out

Tags: html, css, overflow, responsive

I built a responsive website, and on desktop - whenever the user zooms in, first it changes it's layout to tablet, but that's not the main problem -when I zoom out again, the whole page layout breaks.

I figured out that it happens because my main-wrapper div (which wraps the whole content of the body tag) has `overflow: hidden;` applied to it, which I use to hide the menues and slides when not displayed.

Any Ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Can you hide your menus and slides in a different way?

Comment: It would be a problem now after the whole site was build that way...

Answer (score 0):

try changing overflow to auto and changing the max-height of your menus to calc(100vh - 64px) or calc(100vw - 64px) for the max-width

```css
body {
  overflow: auto;
}
.menu, .slides {
  max-width: calc(100vw - 64px);
  max-height: calc(100vh - 64px);
}
```